# R: How to fill missing values by means for each level?

Tags: r

The data is complex. I reduced the data to a minimum example.

```
X Y
1 10
1 15
1 NA
2 30
2 40
2 NA
```

I want to fill the NA by means for each level in R. It seems quiet complex and may relates to function `apply` or something else.

The result should be

```
X Y
1 10
1 15
1 (10 + 15)/2
2 30
2 40
2 (30 + 40)/2
```

Comment: Something like `with(df, ave(Y, X, FUN = function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), mean(x, na.rm = TRUE), x)))` could work.

Comment: I find the easiest way is to use `caret` packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be easily done with `na.aggregate` from `zoo`.  If we are using `data.table` (for group by operations), convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'x', we replace the `NA` values by the `mean` values with `na.aggregate` and assign (`:=`) that to a new column ('Y1').

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
setDT(df1)[, Y1:= na.aggregate(Y), by = X]
df1
#   X  Y   Y1
#1: 1 10 10.0
#2: 1 15 15.0
#3: 1 NA 12.5
#4: 2 30 30.0
#5: 2 40 40.0
#6: 2 NA 35.0
```

If we don't need a new column and if the 'Y' column is `integer` class, the output `class` should match that.  By doing `mean`, the `class` would change to `numeric`.  So make sure that the initial 'Y' class is `numeric` before assigning the values.

```
setDT(df1)[, Y:= as.numeric(Y)][, Y:= na.aggregate(Y), X]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tapply` to create a lookup table which can be used as a tool to retrieve mean for each category.

```
df <- data.frame(X=c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), Y=c(10, 15, NA, 30, 40, NA))
match_table <- tapply(df$Y, df$X, mean, na.rm=TRUE)
match_table
#   1    2 
# 12.5 35.0 

NA_position <- which(is.na(df$Y))

df$Y[NA_position] <- match_table[df$X[NA_position]]
df
#   X    Y
# 1 1 10.0
# 2 1 15.0
# 3 1 12.5
# 4 2 30.0
# 5 2 40.0
# 6 2 35.0
```